# viewpager with tabLayout scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have three nested fragments (inside a main fragment) that I implement using `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. In my main fragment i have a `Spinner` view that filters the content of the first two fragments. However, i do not want this `Spinner` view to appear in my third fragment. To implement it I use `addOnPageChangeListener()` as shown below:

`mallDropDown` is my `Spinner` view.

However, this implementation works only if i select the fragments by clicking on the title. If i scroll through the fragments by swiping then it is very unstable i.e. sometimes the `Spinner` appears when it shouldn't have and so on.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mallDropDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mallDropDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mallDropDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        mallDropDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: did you tried handle this in on PageScrolled() too?

Answer (score 1):

Check this onPageScrollStateChanged, it may work

```
@Override 
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
           super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
           if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                   // hide if not
                }
            }
```